# NFA to DFA and Regular Expression

Tags: automata, regular-expressions, finite-automata

The truth is that my teacher gave us a homework, and I wanted to ask you if I did this right.

What I have to do is answer the following questions given the following NFA.

[image: NFA]

1. Why is this an NFA?
2. What language describes the NFA? Describe in your words and indicate
   the corresponding regular expression
3. Transform it into a DFA and indicate their dead, initial and final
   states.

So my answers are...

1. Because it holds that: $\delta(q_1, \epsilon) = q_{14}, \text{with } q_1 \neq q_{14} (\text{in a DFA is always true that $\delta(q, \epsilon) = q$})$ and $\delta(q_2, \epsilon) = q_3, \delta(q_2, \epsilon) = q_7, \text{with } q_3 \neq q_7 (\text{in a DFA if $\delta(q, a) = q_1$ and $\delta(q, a) = q_2, \text{then is always true that } q_1 = q_2$})$.
2. The regular expression is $1(11|0^*)^*$, that is, the set of strings containing $0$s and $1$s starting with a $1$, having an odd number of $1$s and wherein each $1$ after the first, will be accompanied by at least another $1$.
3. The DFA I got was this.

[image]

Initial state: A, Final states: C, D, E and Dead state: B.

I did it well?

Comment: I would give that answer full marks, although I do notice that you can merge states D and F of your DFA.  (In fact, it's possible to write a DFA with only 4 states. I *think* once you merge D and F it will be clear that you can also merge them with C.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with regard to what you say that I can merge D, F and C, is there a way to transform the NFA to DFA with fewer states algorithmically?, or is it by guess?, because of the way I did (applying e-closure to the states to the initial state, etc...) it resulted in exactly the DFA that I show on the last picture.

Comment: You are looking for the Myhill-Nerode theorem.

Comment: @MJD The minimal DFA has 3 states and even just 2 states if you allow incomplete automata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A DFA has no $\epsilon$-transitions, so this is not a DFA. I would rather called your automaton a [nondeterministic finite automaton with $\varepsilon$-moves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton_with_%CE%B5-moves).
2. Your regular expression $1(11 \cup 0^*)^*$ is correct. Your informal description is almost correct: you should just modify your sentence

> each $1$ after the first, will be accompanied by at least another $1$

as follows:

> if one counts only the $1$, every $1$ in **even** position is followed by a $1$.

The problem with your formulation occurs for instance for the word $1110$: this word is in the language, however the third $1$ is not followed by a $1$.

3. **Hint**. The minimal automaton has actually 3 states.
4. For the question in your comment see the answer to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40819/how-to-create-dfa-from-regular-expression-without-using-nfa/40828#40828).

Comment: One might also mention that it fails to be a DFA because it’s missing some of the required transitions, e.g., a $0$ transition from $q_0$.

Comment: @brian-m-scott Some authors do not require this condition and refer to *complete* deterministic automata for a DFA with this property. See in particular, Eilenberg's definition p. 30 in his book Automata, Languages and Machines, Vol A, Academic Press, 1974.